# How to make contacts.google.com work in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-contacts, permissions

The site contacts.google.com doesn't work on Google Chrome 14 for me, I tried on multiple accounts. It works on Firefox.

**NOTE**: originally I thought the problem started when I removed the permissions for that application, but as it occurs in multiple accounts where it didn't happen I edited the question.

Comment: What message does it give when you try to access the site?

Comment: @Andrew no message, I only see the top bar that is common to all Google pages and a blank page

Comment: How did you manage to remove permissions?

Comment: Perhaps you're logged in to another Google or Google Apps account. Multi-login does strange things to me sometimes. Could you give us more information?

Comment: @NullUserException I removed the permission at my Account Settings IssuedAuthSubTokens page https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en

Comment: @Eugenio Perea I'm not logged to multiple accounts in this browser, I cleared all cookies

Comment: It works just fine for me with Chrome 14. It immediately redirects to http://www.google.com/contacts/u/0

Comment: Try opening it in Incognito mode (that will disable extensions and other things that might be interfering with the site).  It's not a global problem, Google Contacts works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: @AndrewMaiman it worked, one extension caused the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site seems to be incompatible with the [Image Search by Cooliris](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllgofbnhaihnfbokejhcndhoogagdmk?hc=search&hcp=ext) extension. When I disable it, the page works.